# filter_var returns false with valid emails

Tags: php, email, filter-var, filter-validate-email

i made a function that takes the emails from a csv and stores them in the database, but the problem is that filter_var is returning false.

I have this in a loop

```
$email = trim(str_replace('"', "", $row[0]));
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    //save
}else{
    echo "failed: -$email-".mb_detect_encoding($email)."<br/>";
}
```

When executed, it echos all emails meaning it's failing, but the echoed emails are valid, theres no spaces or quotes or anything, i've placed dashes before and after to see if there were any.

```
failed: -email@gmail.com-ASCII
```

Is it failing because of the aschii encoding?

Comment: Show `var_dump($email)` after failed validation.

Comment: csv failed: -exxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com-ASCII
string(41) "exxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"

i've replaced characters with x for privacy but that's the real length of the email, hmm its says "string(41)"

Comment: **FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL** - Validates whether the value is a valid e-mail address.In general, this validates e-mail addresses against the syntax in `RFC 822`, with the exceptions that comments and whitespace folding are not supported.And read about `RFC 822` - https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/rfc/822addr.html

Comment: but there's no white spaces, what you see between the dashes is what im trying to filter.

edit, i;ve added $email = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),"",$email); after the trim, still nothing